# How to get the button index value in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, indexing

I have created the buttons are dynamically. Now i want to get the button index value.

Here my code is,
For Eg,
My Array,

```
 {
    one, 
    two,
    three,
    Four
 }

 int x = 10;

 for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {

 UIButton *answerBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

 [answerBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(30, x, 260, 40)];

 answerBtn.tag = i; 

 [answerBtn setTitle:[answerList objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 NSString *actualString = @"two";

 NSString *getString = [answerList objectAtIndex:i];

 if([actualString isEqualToString:getString])
 {

  //How do i get the correct values of array index, In this case i want to return the index value is 1. Bcoz the array[1] = two.
  NSLog(@"The btn tag is %d", answerBtn.tag); // couldn't get correct index   
 }

 [self.view addSubview: answerBtn];
}
```

Expected result is,

```
  The btn tag is 1.
```

Comment: Did you actually set the tag?

Comment: @Richard J Ross, Yes, I have edited my question,please see the question now.

Comment: @Pugal I do not see which button you are trying to get the tag from. `answerBtn`'s tag will always be equal to `i`.

Comment: @Richard J Ross, I have already used this code NSLog(@"The btn tag is %d", answerBtn.tag);, But i couldn't get the correct index. SO how can i get the correct button index?. Thanks

Comment: @Pugal I do not understand still. What do you mean by correct index? Index of what? if you are basing it off of the title of the button, you need `answerBtn.tag + 1`.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III,  NSString *actualString = @"two";
  NSString *getString = [answerList objectAtIndex:i];(My array values like,   one, two, three, four)

 if([actualString isEqualToString:getString])
  { 
       // If this condition is true and i want to return the value is 1 (Bcoz the first index string is "two")
  } Did you get my point now?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"The btn tag is %d", answerBtn.tag);
```

Comment: What does this code accomplish though? `answerBtn`'s tag will always be equal to i.

Comment: that question isn't too hard to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the button tag to get it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {

 UIButton *answerBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

 answerBtn.tag = i;

 [answerBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(30, x, 260, 40)];

 [answerBtn setTitle:[answerList objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 NSString *actualString = @"two";

 NSString *getString = [answerList objectAtIndex:i];

 if([actualString isEqualToString:getString])
 {
    //How do i get the correct button index, In this case i want to return the tag is 1.
  NSLog(@"The btn tag is %d", answerBtn.tag); // it's not w
 }



[self.view addSubview: answerBtn];
}
```

Comment: What does this code accomplish though? `answerBtn`'s tag will always be equal to i.

Comment: You button will have tag's 0, 1, 2, ...,n-1, and the you can get back you button from your view     UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:0]; Then you can do any mods you want to the button.